# iOS - git merge conflicts after adding cocoapods to project

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods, xcode-project, xcode-workspace

I'm working on an app with another partner. He's been working on master, and I started a new branch. On my branch I installed `cocoapods`. I just tried pulling from master and I'm getting merge conflicts.

When I open up Xcode, the workspace file has an error and it says:

```
"Workspace Integrity - Couldn't load project"
```

How can I solve this merge conflict?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When git encounters merge conflicts, it adds lines of text to the conflicting files.
They're comments like:

```
<<<<< HEAD
  ... your code from HEAD...
=========
  ... your code from the merge branch...
>>>>>> my_merged_branch_name
```

These lines mark where Git needs help. When Xcode runs into one of these lines in a `.pbxproj` file, it is unable to open the file and it throws an `Workspace Inconsistency` error.

If you look at the messages you got from git, they show which files had the merge conflicts.

To fix the problem:

1. Open each of those file with a simple text editor (I'm old school, so I use vi. Nano will also work. Just make sure you use a code editor and not word processor like TextEdit that will try to change your line endings, etc. )
2. Resolve the conflicts by removing the comment lines added by git, and deciding which lines of code to keep.
3. Then tell git that you have resolved the conflicts:
   git add .
4. and continue with the merge.

Xcode should now be able to open your project.

Comment: How can we look at the messages we got from git? You told like that, but I can't find. Glad if you can help.

Comment: Ah. Hmm. I use Git from the command line, so it prints a message when there's a merge conflict. However, the text `>>>>` and `=====` are not messages. Git actually **adds those lines to your code**. To fix the conflict, you have to remove those lines (and adjust your code if you need to). When those lines are added to a `.pbxproj` file, Xcode gives the error in the question title. Just open up the .pbxproj file and search for >>>>.

Comment: Yeah okay, I mean, I was looking for a list of conflicting files. I explicitly each my file because I couldn't get that list, including pbxproj too. Anyway, thanks, you made it work

Answer (score 9):

Here is my 2 Cents.

Sometimes even after deleting all of the `>>>>` and `=====` still you get the same errors.

- Clean the project,
- Run the `pod install`
- Build the project

This should fix the remaining issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your project.pbxproj is destoryed. if you changed your project.pbxproj,you should check your project.pbxproj carefully by your.xcodeproj -->show Package contents -->project.pbxproj

Comment: I meet the same issue because i deleted a more semicolon when i fix merge conflict.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to resolve conflicts, when you cannot access workspace files is to press `⌘` + `⌥` + `c` and should see every single conflict which leads to the error `"Workspace Integrity - Couldn't load project".`

If you are not sure what's wrong with pods or Carthage; you can right-click on pod/Carthage and `discard changes`. You can later update those pods manually.

Answer (score 0):

Most chances you have an issue with the `project.pbxproj` file which is inside your `ProjectName.xcodeproj` (right click show package content).

You can read up [in github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8906) about a similar issue and there's also a "lint" solution you [can try](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8906#issuecomment-520109543).

I think a faster solution would be moving the `HEAD` "backwards" in git over each commit until your project file works and once it works, move the `HEAD` 1 commit "forward" and see the changes in `project.pbxproj`, you will probably see missing closing/opening brackets or perhaps missing  semicolon.

Now, that you know what is missing, go to the latest commit and manually  fix your `project.pbxproj` file using a simple text viewer.

Good luck.